# Escape special characters of html string in java

Tags: java, html, escaping, special-characters

I have a html content as a string.

```
String attachment = "<div style=\"color:black;font-style:normal;font-size:10pt;font-family:verdana;\"><div><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255,255,255);\">This is special "'; </span></div></div>";
```

If I try to add this as a multipart form data I get an exception. The reason happens to be the special characters inside the html which is " and '. So I tried escaping the entire string using

> org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJave(attachment);

After doing this the exception disappeared and it was working fine. But the double quotes used for the attributes, like style are also escaped using this method, which is not desired.

Instead of `<div> style="color:black;`

it was sent as `<div> style=\"color:black;`

So far I realized that I need to escape only the text inside the html content and not the entire text. i could extract the text content using jsoup or something else then form the html again.

But is there a generic easy solution to do this?

Comment: You could regex that and only escape strings between `<` and `>`, but there would also always be the possibility that the string contains those letters.

Comment: Yes that's a possibility. < and > symbols could also be inside the text.

Comment: Can you try this "<div style='color:black;font-style:normal;font-size:10pt;font-family:verdana;'><div><span style='background-color: rgb(255,255,255);'>This is special</span></div></div>"

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you are trying to do? Have you considered concatenating the strings after applying/not applying proper escaping an option (eg. `String attachment = "<div>" + escapeHtml("some content") + "</div>"`) ? Fiddling with regex etc. to  feels wrong - and almost always leads to security issues.

Comment: @fateddy Consider I get this string from some other server as a whole. I am just trying to post it to another server. I narrowed down the problem to escaping the special characters present in the text body of any html I get. In this particular example the quote after "this is special" should be escaped but not the quote after "div style=".